# Script to disable email signatures in default Android email app

Tags: email, scripts, airwatch

We use Airwatch to manage our company phones, and the task was handed to me to make sure the "Sent from..." default was disabled.

Is it possible to create a script that could be pushed out to turn off the Signature option on the default Android email app?

Thanks for any help you can give!